Logging commands are successfully logging the script, but it is preventing the commands from outputting to the user
I'm very new to bash scripting. I have a script that I have been working on, everything is working so far but when I include the following section of logging, it doesn't out put commands to the user, only to the log file. Here is the logging section of the script.
exec 3>&1 1>"$logfile" 2>&1
trap "echo 'ERROR: An error occurred during execution, check log $logfile for details.' >&3" ERR
# recieving user info to set up variables
echo "Please type INC number"
read incnumber

Im not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I remove the logging part, everything works and displays fine.

Removing 2>&1 will show the output, most likely. Hard to say without seeing more of the code.

By saying exec … 1>"$logfile" 2>&1, you are sending all stdout and stderr to the log file.  3>&1 doesn't really help much.  If you want output to go to both the pre-existing stdout (typically the terminal) and the log file, look at tee; but see also programs like tmux and script. It would help if you would define exactly what behavior you want.

... see also Using exec and tee to redirect logs to stdout and a log file in the same time
